# Rails is posting it's syntax out loud when it should be running behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, firebug

See update: for answer at bottom

Original question:

I have a `<script></script>` in my page and when it runs it does:-

```
<% Route.all.each do |route| %>
  var long = "<%= route.longitude %>";
  var lati = "<%= route.latitude %>";
  var title = "Route <%= route.route_number %> Stop <%= route.stop_number %>";
  var id = "<%= route.id %>";
<% end %>
```

But in `Firebug` I'm getting this error in console.

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   
<% Route.all.each do |route| %>
 ^
```

**Update:** Turns out to be a firebug issue, works as intended but firebug will post as an error.

Comment: what's the extension of the file where this code lives?

Comment: admin.html.erb (15 char limit)

Comment: that is indeed weird. can you add the whole template in a gist?

Comment: @jvnill https://gist.github.com/Gacnt/7dfbddba3979f3800b0d line 37

Comment: @jvnill hm, when I view source it actually doesnt show it, but firebug picks it up, any idea why that is?

Comment: @jvnill I guess it is working as intended, but it's weird that firebug picks it up but doesn't show it in the view source

Comment: yep weird indeed. upvoting

Comment: Still doesn't look right to me. That looks like ERB server-side code that is reaching your client uninterpreted, as is. Do you happen to have JS response that is spewing out that ERB code as is because it is in a HAML template? Asking, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This is either related to your environment ("production" doesn't show detailed error and debug info)

Or related to firebug itself 
(god bless them, couldn't live without it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<< your script code >>

</script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because js variables long, lati, title and id are defined more than once: each instance route of a Route generates a *definition* of all these four variables. 
To avoid this, define them once before the loop with an empty value '' and then remove "var " before them in the loop.

```
var long = ""; var lati = ""; var title = ""; var id = "";
<% Route.all.each do |route| %>
 long = "<%= route.longitude %>";
 lati = "<%= route.latitude %>";
 title = "Route <%= route.route_number %> Stop <%= route.stop_number %>";
 id = "<%= route.id%>";
<% end %>
```